# git proxy server for pull and clone requests

Tags: git

I need to create a proxy server on linux, that will accept requests for clone, pull and checkout from a specific private repo.

I do not want to give the users direct access to github, and do not want to give them any github passwords or keys.

My idea is to create a proxy server on linux, that the user can access using a password or key, and that forwards the request to the repo and performs authentication which is all hidden from the user.

I dont have any code snippets for this one, as I'm really not sure if / how it could be done !

Most important thing is the user should not know the github details, and the proxy needs to perform authentication using ssh / deploy keys.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can do this ??

**Update**

Well thanks so much for all of the comprehensive and fast suggestions, but there are a few things I forgot to include:

1. Customers don't have github accounts
2. I want to selectively control (allow/block) their ability to access the repo using my own authentication independent of github.

And it seems that with nodejs http-proxy it is trivial:

```
const username = 'mygitid';
const password = 'mygitpwd';
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
var url = `https://github.com/dmygitid/some-repo.git`;

  var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
  
  const ssl = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','myssl.net.key'), 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'ssl','myssl.net.crt'), 'utf8')
  }

  httpProxy.createServer({
    ssl     : ssl,
    target  : url,
    secure  : false,
    auth    : auth
  }).listen(8111)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to give their users read-only access to the repository?

Comment: because they are customers not collaborators :-)

Comment: You can just use HTTP authentication with the dumb HTTP protocol. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> accept requests for clone, pull and checkout

That means read-only access? There are four easy methods to do this:

| Possibility | Accessibility | access to issue/PR tracker | authentication |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Make it public | everyone | yes | no |
| Give customers read-only access | only specific customers | yes | yes |
| Make a mirror repository on your server | everyone with access to the server | no | Yes |
| Make a mirror repository on GitHub | everyone | seperate issue/PR tracker | No (but you could only allow it for some GitHub users) |
| Make your own HTTP proxy | everyone with access to your proxy | No | Your proxy authentication |

---

## Make it public

The easiest method is (obviously) to make the repository public but customers can see issues/pull requests, there.

This is only an option if everyone should be able to see the repository (and issues/PRs, etc.)

---

## Give customers read-only access

Why don't you want to give their users read-only access to the repository? This is the easiest way and the users don't have to much permissions.

In an organisation repository, you can configure this under `Settings`>`Manage access` by clicking on `Invite teams or people`:

[image: Image of the Manage Access menu]

You can there select read-only permissions.

[image: Image of inviting people/teams]

As you see there, you can also create a "team" and assign your customers to that team.

This requires adding the customers to your organisation, however.

---

## Make a mirror repository on your server

However, if you really want to create a "proxy server", you can just use a repository that is a clone of the other one.

Basically, you first need to clone the repository using the `--bare` option.

`--bare` means you clone it without checking it out.

You can then set up a cron job that automatically runs `git pull` every amount of time in order to update the other repository.

The easiest access for you to give access to the mirror repository is to use the `dumb` http protocol. It is a read only protocol and you just need to set up an HTTP(s) server that exposes your `.git` directory.

Customers can then clone it using `git clone https://yourproxy.com/path/to/.git`.

However, the dumb http protocol is a bit slow. A faster way to access a read-only git repository is the git protocol.

You can look at [Chapter 4.5 of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon) on how to set up the git protocol.

This will not expose your issues/PRs source code is still visible. You have control over the mirror and only allow some customers to access it but you will need to maintain a server.

The mirror repository will not be instantly updated, however. In order to bypass this issue, you could use something like GitHub Actions in order to mirror it whenever someone pushes.

You can just require HTTP authentication for the dumb protocol in order to only allow it for some users. See [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) and [this](https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747) for details.

---

## Make a mirror repository on GitHub

As [jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing) pointed out in the comments, you could also set up a new (mirror) GitHub repository that automatically updates using GitHub Actions.

You create the (public) other repository and add an action that is executed automatically whenever someone pushes to your repository. It clones the repository and pushes it to the mirror repository using a deploy key or PAT.

This will not expose your issues/PRs source code is still visible. You also have a seperate issue tracker for the mirror repository. Everyone can see source code (and issue tracker) of the mirror.

---

## Make your own HTTP proxy

As you suggested, you can also use your own proxy that would require authentication.

In that case, you will need to swap your authentication with the github authentication. For simplicity, create a GitHub Account with read-only permissions and swap out your authentication with the authentication from your account when forwarding the requests to GitHub.

However, you might need to change the authentication method as GitHub might not support the authentication method you want.

Comment: You could also use a github action on your main repo to mirror your private repo, or even just push specific branches to a read-only repo on GitHub which your clients can access. I assume you want to hide the issue tracking from them?!

Comment: You could but I am not sure if the he wants everyone to access the repository copy (maybe only people with access to the server). However, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: He could push to a private repo and secure it separately.

Comment: Yeah, I know. He could also use hooks in order to mirror/publish it.